# Is there any way to implement prisma studio inside nestjs application?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I have a nestjs application that uses prisma+postgresql. I use Prisma Studio for development purposes, which speeds up the development process a lot, I can easily delete/write/edit data in my tables.

By standard prisma studio runs on localhost:5555. Is there any way I can implement studio in nestjs application?Let me explain what I mean and why I need it - I, as an admin, want to have remote access to the admin panel. As an admin panel I want to use prisma studio, it contains all the functionality that I will need as an admin. And I want to just go to the guarded route /admin and have prisma studio open when I request this route.

Or are there any other similar tools to manage database tables, as an admin?

Comment: As the command only allows to configure `port` and `browser`, which both are irrelevant for you question, it does not seem possible to host the studio on your server just like that. I reckon to open a discussion here, https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions regarding this question.